# height overflow doesn't work properly, content shows in the middle of website

Tags: html, css, height, responsive

I set the height to 520px but i would like the website to be responsive and height to be dynamic.
The problem is that whenever i try to add `min-height:100px; overflow:auto;` content starts to show in the middle of the page, hiding behind one div above. I tried also `height:fit-content`and it also didin't work. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="content">
                            <div class="leftimg">
                                <img src="../img/img.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="righttext">
                            <div>
                            <span class="topic">text</span>
                            </div><br>
                            <span class="desc">
text
                            </span>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
.righttext{
  display:block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
  float: right;
  font-family: teko;
  text-align: center;
  border-left:2px dashed #ffffff;
  height: 90%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
}

.leftimg{
  display:block;
  width: 43%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  align-items: center;
}

.desc{
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.topic{
  font-size: 3em;
}

.content{
  position: relative;
    display: block;
  background-color: #76C9F0; 
  height:520px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
 .content{
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}
 .leftimg{
  display:none !important;
}

.righttext{
  width: 90% !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed white;
  border-left: none !important;
}
 }
```

What would be the simpliest solution to make responsive dynamic height for the current problem? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnHAH.png)

Comment: Try using the min-height:100vh. Hope this is what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @SamPhilemon unfortunately it just makes bigger gap between bottom border and text https://ibb.co/Fnm9gHr

Answer (score 0):

So you can try this and see if this fixes the issue. So I have commented out the transform property and added the `overflow: auto` in the .content file.

```css
.righttext {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
  float: right;
  font-family: teko;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px dashed #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  /* -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); */
  /* transform: translateY(-50%); */
}

.leftimg {
  display: block;
  width: 43%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  /* -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); */
  /* transform: translateY(-50%); */
  align-items: center;
}

.desc {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.topic {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #76c9f0;
  /* height: 520px; */
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .content {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .leftimg {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .righttext {
    width: 90% !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed white;
    border-left: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="leftimg">
    <img src="../img/img.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="righttext">
    <div>
      <span class="topic">text</span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <span class="desc">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
        since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
        scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
        centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
        of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
        with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
        typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
        text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
        and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
        five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
        of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
        with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum.
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```